# プロジェクト内の動画ファイルをローカライズする方法について

Tags: ios

英語版StackOverflowとのクロスポストです。

iOSアプリで、複数の言語で異なる動画を表示したいです。

1. project -> Info -> Localizationsで「Use Base Internationalization」のチェックを外す。
2. Englishをデフォルトにする。
3. Japaneseを追加する。
4. 動画をプロジェクトに追加する。
5. 動画を選択してXcodeの右パネルで「Localize...」をクリック。
6. EnglishとJapaneseにチェックを入れる。
7. en.lproj と ja.lproj のファイルをFinderでそれぞれの言語のバージョンに置き換える。
8. 以下のコードで動画のURLを取得する： `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "The movie", withExtension: "mp4")`
9. アプリを実行すると日本語版が再生される（シミュレータの言語が日本語なので）
10. 実行スキームを編集して「App Language」をEnglishに変更。
11. アプリを実行すると日本語版が再生される（期待している動作は、英語版が再生されることです）。

[image: Xcodeの左ペイン]

何が問題なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Clean Build Folder..." を実行すると期待した動作になりました。

シミュレーター内のアプリバンドル（拡張子が.appのファイル）を確認すると、古いローカライズされていないバージョンの動画ファイルが残っていました。そこで、"Clean Build Folder..."を実行し再度ビルドすると、ローカライズされたバージョンの動画がアプリ内に表示されました。